# Why is $\log(1+e^x) - \frac{x}{2}$ even?

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm dealing with Fourier series and I'm trying to figure out $\log(1+e^x) - \frac{x}{2}$ is even??? I've tried the $f(-x) = f(x)$ method but it doesn't give me the equality. But I've plotted it, and it is even? :S

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This question seemed ripe for a Taylor series expansion, but I don't immediately see that it helps.

Comment: It would work fine (although I don't know if OP has worked with those):  the only thing keeping $ \ \log(1+e^x) \ $ from being even turns out to be the $ \ \frac{x}{2} \ $ term in the series.

Comment: The Taylor series of $f(x) := \log(1+e^x)$ around $x_0=0$ will give you a null coefficients $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for every odd terms
$$ f^{(n)}(x_0) \frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!} = f^{(n)}(0) \frac{x^n}{n!},$$ 
except for the first, which will be $f'(0)=1/2$, giving you the $f'(0) \frac{x}{1!}=x/2$ that will cancel out with the $-x/2$.  
Unfortunately, it will be tiresome to do all the math.  I was doing it, but then took an arrow to the knee.  =D

Answer (score 27):

$$\begin{align}
\ln(1+e^x)-\frac x2  &=  \ln(1+e^x)-\ln(e^{\frac x2}) \\
&= \ln\left((1+e^x)e^{\frac {-x}2}\right) \\
&=\ln(e^{\frac {-x}2} +e^{\frac x2}) \\
\end{align}$$
From this it should be obvious that the function is indeed even.

Comment: +1 It might be mentioned that you nicely "unmask" this function as being $ \ \ln ( \  \cosh \left[ \frac{x}{2} \right] \ ) \ $ , the logarithm of an even and always positive function, and thus expected to be even.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner A little nitpicking, but shouldn't it be $ \ln \left( 2\cosh ( \frac{x}{2} ) \right )$? :)

Comment: Yes, I slipped a factor of  $ \ 2 \ $ :  I went back to check it using the "double-angle formula" for cosh and see that I goofed using the first formula I applied.

Answer (score 6):

Another way of treating this is that a continuous function $ \ f(x) \ $ can be "separated" into "even" and "odd" components,

$$ f_e(x) \ = \ \frac{f(x) \ +  \ f(-x)}{2} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \  f_o(x) \ = \ \frac{f(x) \ -  \ f(-x)}{2} \ \ . $$

Here, we have

$$   f_o(x) \ = \ \frac{[ \ \log(1+e^x) \ - \ \frac{x}{2} \ ] \ -  \ [ \ \log(1+e^{-x}) \ - \ \frac{(-x)}{2} \ ]}{2}  $$

$$ = \ \frac{ \ \log(1+e^x) \  -  \  \ \log(1+e^{-x}) \ - \ x }{2}  $$

$$ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ \left[ \ \log \left(\frac{1+e^x}{1+e^{-x}} \right)   \  - \ x \ \right] \  = \ \frac{1}{2} \ \left[ \ \log \left(\frac{e^x \ [1+e^x]}{e^x+1} \right)   \  - \ x \ \right] \ \ $$

$$ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ [ \ \log (e^x  )   \  - \ x \ ] \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{2} \ [ \ x  \  - \ x \ ] \ = \ 0 \ \ . $$

Our function has zero "odd component", so it is purely even.  [We could also have shown that $ \ f_e(x) \ = \ f(x) \ $ .]

Comment: +1. Note that this apply to all (real-valued) functions, not only the continuous ones.

Comment: I was "playing it safe":  this function is continuous everywhere, so the technique would definitely work here.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you say that checking $f(-x)=f(x)$ doesn't work? Of course it does. $\ddot\smile$ $$\ln(1+e^{-x})-\frac{-x}2=\ln\frac{e^x+1}{e^x}+\frac x2=\ln(e^x+1)-\ln e^x+\frac x2=\\=\ln(1+e^x)-x+\frac x2=\ln(1+e^x)-\frac x2$$